# ResultSet.getMetaData gives incompatible Types error

Tags: java, jdbc

```
 ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from dbo.employeeDetails");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData(); //getting error here!!
```

error: incompatible types

[image]

Why I am getting this error?
(PFA for the error message)

Comment: Please show the whole error message

Comment: edited the post with snapshot of error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named your class is `ResultSetMetaData` which doesn't contain the methods found in `java.sql.ResultSetMetaData`.